# Select into an array of composite types in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Are composite type arrays the correct way to simulate a "function scoped" table in plpgsql?

I want to store the results of a query for access throughout the function,
but I don't want to use a temp table because a single session may execute multiple function calls concurrently.

```
DECLARE 
projectDocuments document_tracking.docmaster[];

SELECT * INTO projectDocuments FROM document_tracking.docmaster WHERE jobnumber = jobnumberparam;
```

Produces the malformed array literal error, am I supposed to use aggregate functions, or :=?

Comment: `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` is not an option?..

Comment: Do you mean to create a temp table and specify ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS.  Does this mean the temp table is locked in the function's transaction, and concurrently executing functions will lock themselves if necessary?

Comment: It's not locked. it is populated inside transaction and on commit gets empty. how you want to implement concurrency in same session?.. statement level sharing in a pool?.. In not - it will work. if yes - depends where you do it - if in function - maybe will work. I'm even curious to try :)

Comment: It will be called as part of a trigger.  The caller will be an api request from a web application, if two api calls trigger this function, it should make them execute concurrently, no?

Comment: I think you've answered my question though, since each api call will be part of a seperate transaction, the delete on commit should prevent any changes being made to the table outside of the function.  But since the function will be called multiple times in the same transaction I should always delete from it when it's called.  Thanks ^_^!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using

```
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

> All rows in the temporary table will be deleted at the end of each
>   transaction block. Essentially, an automatic TRUNCATE is done at each
>   commit.